# sql server use computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query like this:

```
select 
(price1 + price2 + price3) as total_price 
from prices
```

How can i use the computed column total_price to compute other total like this?

```
select 
(price1 + price2 + price3) as total_price,
(price4 + total_price) as total_price2
from prices
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `Is this possible?`, have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Ofcourse I tried it. I get an "invalid column total_price" message.
Is what i'm trying to accomplish possible?

Comment: Not inside the same query - query processor can't use output columns as input columns. You need either write formulas out every time or make inner query, which calculates first level computed columns and then select from that query, calculating next level formulas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No it isn't possible to reference the column alias defined at the same level. Expressions that appear in the same logical query processing phase are [evaluated as if at the same point in time](http://www.ndc2010.no/index.aspx?id=268800).

[As Joe Celko says](http://joecelkothesqlapprentice.blogspot.com/2006/06/reference-alias-field-name.html)

> Things happen "all at once" in SQL, not "from left to right" as they
>   would in a sequential file/procedural language model

You can define it in a CTE and then re-use it outside the CTE however.

Example

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT ( price1 + price2 + price3 ) AS total_price,
                price4
         FROM   prices)
SELECT total_price,
       ( price4 + total_price ) AS total_price2
FROM   T
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd also consider a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) on the table if this will used often

```
ALTER  TABLE prices ADD
   total_price AS (price1 + price2 + price3)
```

Then your query is

```
select 
    total_price,
    (price4 + total_price) as total_price2
from prices
```

This way, you can apply the DRY principle...

Answer (score 1):

```
select T.total_price,
       P.price4 + T.total_price as total_price2
from prices as P
  cross apply (select P.price1 + P.price2 + P.price3) as T(total_price)
```