# SQL - Derived field in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sql server use computed column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135774/sql-server-use-computed-column)

Is there a way to do this:

```
select Name, 
    (SELECT Max(reference) 
        from Rematch 
        WHERE Gender='M' and convert(varchar,getdate,103) = '08/10/2012'
    ) As MaxReferenceMale, 
    (SELECT Max(reference) 
        from Rematch 
        WHERE Gender='F' and convert(varchar,getdate,103) = '08/10/2012'
    ) As MaxReferenceFemale
WHERE (Gender='M' and Reference > MaxReferenceMale) Or 
    (Gender='F' and Reference > MaxReferenceFemale)
```

I realise there may be better ways of writing the query.  Is it possible to refer to MaxReferenceFemale and MaxReferenceMale in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, SQL Server.  Sorry for missing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick a

```
SELECT * FROM (...) WHERE ...
```

around your query. You can use the aliased columns in your WHERE clause once it's on the inside of the outer SELECT.

Comment: Also known as a subquery or a derived table. And actually you would need to alias the subquery, such as `SELECT * FROM (...) SubqueryAlias WHERE ...`

Comment: You don't *need* to alias the outer query unless you join it to something, but it's a good practice to alias everything.

Comment: @monitorjbl - Depends on DBMS. In SQL Server it is mandatory.

Comment: @Martin Smith - Ah, did not know that, I've never used SQL Server before.

Comment: @monitorjbl, Thanks for the simple and effective solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reference them in the `WHERE` clause, then you will need a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   select Name,  Gender, Reference 
      (SELECT Max(reference) 
        from Rematch 
        WHERE Gender='M' and convert(varchar,getdate,103) = '08/10/2012') As MaxReferenceMale, 
      (SELECT Max(reference) 
        from Rematch WHERE Gender='F' and convert(varchar,getdate,103) = '08/10/2012') As MaxReferenceFemale
) x
WHERE (Gender='M' and Reference > MaxReferenceMale) 
    Or (Gender='F' and Reference > MaxReferenceFemale)
```

Looking at your original query, it looks like you are missing a `FROM` clause in the query, so with a sub-query the syntax will be similar to this:

```
select x.name, x.MaxReferenceMale, x.MaxReferenceFemale
from rematch r
left join
(
    select Name, 
        (SELECT Max(reference) 
            from Rematch 
            WHERE Gender='M' and convert(varchar,getdate,103) = '08/10/2012'
        ) As MaxReferenceMale, 
        (SELECT Max(reference) 
            from Rematch 
            WHERE Gender='F' and convert(varchar,getdate,103) = '08/10/2012'
        ) As MaxReferenceFemale
    from rematch
) x
    on r.name = x.name
WHERE (r.Gender='M' and r.Reference > x.MaxReferenceMale) Or 
    (r.Gender='F' r.and Reference > x.MaxReferenceFemale)
```